# Duda índice de una lista

Tags: python, lista

Hola quisiera saber como dar elementos de una lista usando (índices, lista) se que no es muy claro pero les agradecería que me ayudaran ya que mi profesor no explica nada

Comment: [Te he votado negativamente porque no intentaste nada](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2874/)

Comment: y ya intentaste hacer algo

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so] Nacho. La pregunta es muy confusa, ¿Qué quieres decir con  "dar elementos de una lista"?. Para obtener o asignar valores a una lista usando indexado basta con `lista[indice]`, los indices empiezan en  0 y ha de existir el índice en la lista (en una lista de dos elementos no se puede hacer `lista[2]`). Crea un ejemplo y explica que quieres hacer, que has intentado y cual es el problema o duda concreta que tienes para que podamos ayudarte. Mírate [ask] y [tour] para conocer como hacer buenas preguntas y el funcionamiento general del sitio. Un saludo.

Answer (score 1):

A una lista puedes hacerlo de forma estática con valores que determines o puede ser una consulta hacia alguna fuente de datos, es recomendable usar una estructura como es el arreglo, luego puedes iterar con un bucle para obtener lo que requieres... te dejo dos enlaces relacionados:

```
# empty list
my_list = []

# list of integers
my_list = [1, 2, 3]

# list with mixed datatypes
my_list = [1, "Hello", 3.4]

By https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/list

#!/usr/bin/python

list1 = ['physics', 'chemistry', 1997, 2000];
list2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 ];
print "list1[0]: ", list1[0]
print "list2[1:5]: ", list2[1:5]

By https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_lists.htm
```

Comment: Es mejor que pongas los ejemplos en la publicacion, y no en enlaces ya que si se cayera ese link, la respuesta no tendria informacion necesaria. Mira [answer] para mejorarla. Un saludo

Comment: Buen día, teniendo en cuenta tu comentario he add en la publicación ejemplos de arr para este caso y a su vez en enlace de forma bibliográfica de los mismos para que las paginas sean tenidas en cuenta. Saludos y muchas gracias por tu apreciación sobre mi publicación. Saludos.